# Help with Inequality involving absolute values of trig

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I am trying to wrap my ahead around the following problem:

Prove that for all $x,y$ in $\Bbb R$

$ |\sin(x) - \sin(y)| \leq |x-y|$

And prove that for $x,y$ in $R$

$|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| \leq |x - y|$

My first idea was to use partial derivatives to find relative optima and show that the growth rate of the two sides is different. But that seems like overkill and I don't know how to formally show it.

If I can prove the inequalities for just $-2\pi \leq x ,y\leq 2\pi$ then proving for all of $\Bbb R$ shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Mean value theorem. Ordinary differentiation is all you need.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: @frog: Divide both sides by $|x-y|$. The left-hand side is now $\left|\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}\right|$. What does the mean value theorem say about this quotient?

Comment: It states that for a given x and y there exists a x < a < y such that cos(a) equals that quantity.

Comment: Wait! So can we say that cos(a) is either equal to 1 or less than 1 and this we conclude the inequality is true?

Comment: We're considering only real arguments, hence real values. What can you conclude from $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \equiv 1$ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: have a look at the unit circle and look at $x$ and $y$ as lengths of arcs.

Comment: How do you advance that idea to something formal instead of an intuitive "clearly this is larger"

Comment: Never mind I understand this proof now, we can use a triangle side is less than hypotenuse is less than arclength argument